# Criterion for Uniqueness of Convergence of Sequence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

It is known that in Hausdorff space $X$, if we have convergence sequence in $X$, the limit must be unique. Does there exist weaker criterion for the space? I was thinking if the topology on $X$ satisfies the following property then it will be enough but I am not sure :

For two distinct points $x,y\in X$, we have open neighborhood of $x$ that does not contain $y$ and open neighborhood of $y$ that does not contain $x$.

Is this property equivalent to Hausdorff or not?

Comment: This is the $T_1$ [separation axiom](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Separation_axiom), sometimes attributed to Fréchet in the Kolmogorov classification. It's weaker than Hausdorff, which is the $T_2$ axiom, i.e. there are $T_1$ spaces that are not $T_2$.

Comment: Is it enough for every sequence that converges to converge to unique point?

Comment: The property you are looking for is called *US*. Obviously, T2 $\Rightarrow$ US $\Rightarrow$ T1, but none of these implications is reversible:
https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%20%2B%20~%20T_2 and
https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=T1%20%2B%20~%20US

Comment: @Ulli Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Paul I guess an official answer doesn't make sense, since this question has certainly already been answered on MathStackExchange.

Comment: @Ulli does there exist common property for the spaces to be US?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "common property"? A space is called *US*, if each sequence converges to at most one point. See, for instance, pi-base.

Comment: So do we accept it like "axiom" as in T1 and T2 (Hausdorff) space?

Comment: T1, T2 is not an axiom, it is a definition. And so is US. It's not a matter of acceptance. Spaces do have this property, or not.

Comment: @Ulli Ok I see, I was thinking there is property from T1 plus something that implies US. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property has been called US, and as noted in the comments, is implied by $T_2$, and implies $T_1$. In fact, each of the following distinct properties implies the next.

- [$T_2$](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000003)
- [$k_1$-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000170)
- [KC](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000100)
- [Weakly Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000143)
- [$k_2$-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000171)
- [US](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000099)
- [$T_1$](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000002)